# How to get the UTC time in HH:MM:SS:ms format in Oracle SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, datetime, datetime-format

I have an Oracle SQL statement that fetches the execution time by deducting `startdate` from `enddate' columns. Both the columns stores datetime in UTC format and I am converting them to EST and then getting the execution time by deducting one from another.

When I execute the query in Oracle SQL Developer tool I see the result as '+00 00:00:02.951000' but when I fetch the data from the ResultSet object using java I see the data getting stored in the java string object as '0 0:0:2.951'

How can I convert the string from '+00 00:00:02.951000' to '00:00:02.95' so that it represents the format `HH:MM:SS.ms` format?

**Oracle SQL**

```
select      
  uuid, name, 
  to_char(from_tz(startdate, 'UTC') at time zone 'America/New_York', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as startdate,      
  to_char(from_tz(enddate, 'UTC') at time zone 'America/New_York', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as enddate,      
  (enddate - startdate) as executiontime
from      
  process  
where      
  name = (select name from jobconfiguration where currentprocessid = 'bGd_AAABNaMAAAFQHvY0UyTa');
```

Java code for fetching data from Resultset object:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.ebayenterprise.ecp.jobs.domain.JobHistory;
import com.ebayenterprise.ecp.jobs.utils.GenericUtils;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;

public final class JobHistoryQueryExecutor extends BaseQueryExecutor {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(JobHistoryQueryExecutor.class);

    public JobHistoryQueryExecutor(Connection cn, String sql) {
        super(cn, sql);
    }

    public List<JobHistory> getJobExecutionHistory() {
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        List<JobHistory> jobsHistory = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            stmt = cn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs != null && rs.next()) {
                String uuid = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("UUID"));
                String name = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("NAME"));
                String startDate = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("STARTDATE"));
                String endDate = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("ENDDATE"));
                String executionTime = GenericUtils.getDateToString(rs.getTimestamp("EXECUTIONTIME"));
                String state = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("STATE")).toUpperCase();
                String type = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("TYPE"));
                String parentUuid = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("PARENTUUID"));
                String domainId = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("DOMAINID"));
                String lastModified = StringUtils.defaultString(rs.getString("LASTMODIFIED"));

                //create JobHistory
                JobHistory jobHistory = new JobHistory(uuid, name, startDate, endDate, executionTime, state, type, parentUuid, domainId, lastModified);
                jobsHistory.add(jobHistory);
            }
            LOG.debug("jobsHistory.size() = " + jobsHistory.size());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            LOG.error("Exception while fetching historical data for all jobs.......", ex);
            return null;
        } finally {
            DbUtils.closeQuietly(cn, stmt, rs);
        }
        return jobsHistory;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should calculate the differences in UTC instead of local time so that daylight savings time will not disturb the results. Are the columns declared as `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` in Oracle?

Comment: The columns are declared as `TIMESTAMP` in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat`

```
String executionTime = getDateToString(rs.getTimestamp("EXECUTIONTIME"));

public String getDateToString(final Timestamp date) {
    final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
    df.applyPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    return df.format(date.getTime());
}
```

You need to change the `applyPattern` based on your interested results...

The example above `HH:mm:ss.SSS` prints a time i.e. 22:59:59.999

If you want the datetime you can use: `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS`

You can check the `pattern` values here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Changed my code base to: `String executionTime = GenericUtils.getDateToString(rs.getTimestamp("EXECUTIONTIME"));` but getting following exception:  ` java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: getTimestamp not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CIntervaldsAccessor`

Comment: please update your question with some java code / imports thanks